Signal attenuated in the passband of scipy digital filter
I am trying to filter a signal using a high pass filter. The complete Python code for a minimal working example is below and link to all files here
The problem that I am facing is that the filtered signal is attenuated within the passband. I don't understand why this is and so I am seeking some explanation.
Two images are attached. One is generated from the code. The other is a zoomed in version of what is generated from the code.
If anyone could help me understand why I am getting this result, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!
output
output_zoom
I tried plotting like this to see if I could understand the situation better, but to no avail.
# %% modules
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# %% load data
data = np.load("data.npz")
t = data['t'].squeeze()     # (s)       time vector
dt = np.diff(t)[0]          # (s)       sample period
fs = 1/dt                   # (Hz)      sampling rate
y = data['y'].squeeze()     # (null)    signal

# %% create filter and filter data
# define filter function
def highpass(data: np.ndarray, cutoff: float, sample_rate: float, poles: int = 5):
    sos = sc.signal.butter(poles, cutoff, 'highpass', fs=sample_rate, output='sos')
    filtered_data = sc.signal.sosfiltfilt(sos, data)
    return filtered_data, sos

# filter the data
cutoff = 0.1                                    # (Hz)      cutoff frequency
poles  = 100                                    # (null)    filter order
yF, sosfilt = highpass(y, cutoff, fs, poles)

# %% compute power spectrum
fout1,psd  = sc.signal.welch(y.squeeze(),fs)
fout2,psdF = sc.signal.welch(yF.squeeze(),fs)

# %% plot
fig,ax = plt.subplots(3,1)
fig.tight_layout()

# time domain
axh = ax[0]
axh.plot(t, y)
axh.set(xlabel='Time (s)',
          ylabel='Amplitude')
axh.grid()

# filter characteristics
axh = ax[1]
w, h = sc.signal.sosfreqz(sosfilt, worN=8000,fs=fs)
db = 20 * np.log10(abs(h))
yUB = np.max(db[np.isfinite(db)])
yLB = np.min(db[np.isfinite(db)])
axh.plot(w, db)
axh.fill_betweenx([yLB,yUB],cutoff,fout1[-1],
                    color='g',
                    alpha=0.1)
axh.set(xlabel='Frequency (Hz)',
        ylabel='Filter Freq. Response (db)')
axh.grid()

# power spectrum
axh = ax[2]
yUB = np.max(np.fmax(psd,psdF))
yLB = np.min(np.fmin(psd,psdF))
axh.plot(fout1, psd)
axh.plot(fout2, psdF)
axh.fill_betweenx([yLB,yUB],cutoff,fout1[-1],
                    color='g',
                    alpha=0.1)
axh.set_yscale('log')
axh.set(xlabel='Frequency (Hz)',
          ylabel='Power spectrum')
axh.legend(["Original","Original Filt.","Passband"],loc="lower right")
axh.grid()

plt.savefig("output.png",format="png")
plt.show()
```


For a better understanding why your filtered data is behaving as it is, I would recommend to add the transfer function into the frequency response plots.

poles  = 100. This seems WAY too high for an IIR filter. a) we can't run your code since it requires an external data file. b) start with maybe 3 poles and work your way up from there c) try a unit impulse first, check the transfer function. d) then try a single sine wave in the stop band and the pass band. e) Don't run "real data" until your filter function has been fully unit tested and verified. Chances are that the extremely high filter order creates numerical problems but without the actual data that's hard to tell.

My apologies, the code is here and I edited the post to add this.
Regarding troubleshooting, those are some helpful steps! Thank you!

@Irreducible do you mean showing the numeric expression of the transfer function?

The cutoff (or critical) frequencies of the Butterworth filter (and most other filters used in DSP) defines the point at which gain drops by $1/\sqrt2$ or $-3 \text{dB}$ of the nominal passband gain. If you want less attenuation in your defined passband, you need to decrease the cutoff frequency some.
Why is this $-3\text{dB}$ point considered the edge of the passband? Filter gains have to transition between the passband and stopband region, and cannot perform this transition instantaneously (except in mythical ideal filters). The width of this transition is strongly related to the effective length of the filter's impulse response. Shorter/sharper transitions require longer impulse responses (i.e., higher order). Higher order filters can cause numerical instability because computers have finite precision (e.g., 64-bit), as mentioned by @Hilmar. This $-3\text{dB}$ is also where the attenuation rate commonly becomes somewhat constant (e.g., 20 dB / decade), depending on your filter type and design.
